# Oracle, trigger update backup table in another schema

Tags: oracle11g, triggers

I must trigger an update in another schema table, it could be a simple question, but I stuck on this.

The 2 tables are identical, they have the same data and structure,

The trigger should update: *ADMSCPM98.OPERADOR.NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR*

just after the the

*ADMSCPM.OPERADOR.NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR* update

That's the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UP_OPERADOR
  AFTER UPDATE ON OPERADOR
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE "ADMSCPM98"."OPERADOR"
    SET NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR = :new.NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR        
    WHERE NRO_TENIENTE = :old.NRO_TENIENTE;
END;
/
```

Comment: What is the question?  Are you getting an error?  What error?  Is the code not doing what you expect?  Beyond that, why would you want two tables with identical data and structure rather than dropping one of the two and replacing it with a synonym or a view?